# function in my javascript module is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm writing JavaScript for the browser, my script.js has something like

```
import { foo, bar } from "./lib/sth.js"
function main() { ... }
```

Then I have this in my browser:

```
<script type=module src="./script.js"></script>
<body onload="main();"> ... </body>
```

But it's keep giving me this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: main is not defined
>       at onload ((index):7)

Why is my main now defined? It works fine before I use type=module, but with the import statement, I believe it has to be type=module

Comment: If I am not mistaken, import is not supported natively by browsers. Do you use any compiler to compile your es6 code to plain-old js so that browser can understand it? I think that your whole script.js is not properly loaded because of that. It is not just the main() function. Do you see any other errot before that?

Comment: @AlkisMavridis Sure it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: it doesn't look like script.js is a module

Comment: Module scope != global scope. If you want `main` to be globally available, you need to do this yourself: `window.main = main;`.

Comment: I think you need to enclose modulel in quotes like this `type="module"`. Also export the function in the file. Eg: `export function main(){}`

Comment: You probably shouldn't mix modules with global variables and inline event handler attachment. I would suggest adding something like `window.onload = function () { document.body.onload = main; }`.

Comment: @Royson: Quotes around attribute values are optional in HTML, if the value consists only specific "safe" characters.

Comment: Same confusion in my mind : it's weird that the HTML page that loads the module isn't even aware about functions defined in it ! But the module knows about the HTML page ! Intuitively, that's a complete nonsense...Well, I did like Felix said in his first post and that works. I tried to use "export" before functions but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for @HereticMonkey and @FelixKling!

```
window.onload = function() { ... }
```

does work for my problem. Yet I'm confused why import is designed like this. Suppose I just wanna use some library in my script so I import it, why this makes my script has to be a module as well?

Comment: `why this makes my script has to be a module as well?` well, because you wrote `<script type="module" ...>`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts but if I use import statement without use type=module will cause an syntax error in the browser

Comment: Yes I'm aware, but `import` can only be used in a module scope. That's the whole point.

Comment: That's the part I'm confused, if I use a metaphor in C/C++, I would say module is like ".h", and my scripts is just a regular ".c" file, it does make sense to me if I'm using a ".h" then my own file must be ".h" as well

Comment: Your metaphor doesn't make sense either. A `.h` file is a declaration, while a `.c` is an implementation. It's generally bad practice to declare things in JavaScript without defining them in the same scope. Doing so is what leads to things like [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) and questions that get closed as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: The way it has been designed like this is because JS modules are loaded in "defer" mode, once the rest of the page has been loaded. This is so to allow browser to load and render the page as soon as possible, without waiting for a possibly very huge external, JS module to be loaded and parsed. Hence if you refer to anything from the module BEFORE the page loads i.e. from normal page flow, then you will get the "not found" error as all browsers explicitly defer JS module loading until later.